# How to simulate a component hspice model in multisim

Tags: simulation, spice, multisim, cad, hspice

I'm trying to simulate [TS5A22364](http://www.ti.com/product/TS5A22364/) and they have hspice and ibis models, and CAD model .bxl in Multisim. Is it possible?

I have tried to add the package model but I don't know how to add the .bxl model to Multisim, and the hspice model can't be inserted in the component wizard spice model. Is there any chance I can use this model in my simulation? If it is not possible, what simulator can I use that makes it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use those, but one thing you can expect, in general, is that a model made *specifically* for one simulator, should not work with any other. That goes (I dare say) 100% so for *symbols*. But *subcircuits* and/or *models* that are SPICE-friendly, should work.

In this case, looking at the files, I see the HSPICE files are encrypted (100% sure only works for the program that encrypted it), and IBIS one with unknown language, probably specific to IBIS only. My guess is no, in this case.

Comment: Okay than. So, is there something else I can do to simulate it in my simulator? I mean to use that specific IC into my simulation. Maybe without those HSPICE and IBIS models.

Comment: @juliussin I'm afraid the only way left is to make your own model, unless someone else did that, elsewhere, somewhere. In this case, it's a (relatively) simple task, since you only have SPDTs which could be tweaked to match the graphs, or at least come close enough, maybe even a behavioural approach. How, it's up to you, I can only wish you good luck. :-) But if all you want is some commanded switches, without the burden of bandwidth and specific dynamics, a behavioural approach is best.